# How to control the x and y size of a plot independently?

Tags: plotting

I have this plot

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 200, 
 PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

I would like to change the size along x and y independently because `AspectRatio` changes the size for both by scaling. I want to get a fixed size along x and vary the size along y or vice versa, e.g like this

[image]   [image]   [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
   Plot[
      Sin[x]
      , {x, 0, 10}
      , Frame -> True
      , ImageSize -> {xrange, yrange}
      , PlotStyle -> Red
      , AspectRatio-> yrange/xrange
   ]
   ,{xrange,100,500}
   ,{yrange,100,500}
]
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> I want to get a fixed size along x and vary the size along y or vice
> versa, e.g like

Iam not sure why you say `AscpectRatio` did not work for you? But may be I misunderstood something.

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 200, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, AspectRatio -> #] & /@ Range[4]
```

[image]